# So many missing pieces. Where to look next?

Tags: angularjs

Learning angular is a pretty frustrating process. I've just started the journey down this endless road a couple of weeks ago. I've gone through the [official tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) on the angular website, watched the first 40+ videos on [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons) and read through several other tutorials and examples. I'm new to angular but have a good amount of experience with javascript, jQuery, and knockout, but even after all of the research and examples I've gone through, I still can't piece together even the simplest angular app in a real-world situation.

The problem is that most of these tutorials and examples try to show all the different parts of angular, including controllers, directives, filters, services, $http/$resource, routing, animations, etc.so you end up with this one or two controller app that doesn't have any substance but it incorporates the basics of all of these features. Now, strip away all of the features that aren't really needed for a simple app like $resource, routing, and animations, and add substance to the business logic and data management, and you quickly can see how many holes exist in these tutorials.

For example, a tutorial will show how you can share data between controllers using services. It will go over creating the controller, and using a service to get the data from a server using $http or $resource. Then it will show that even though the request for data is asynchronous, there is rarely a need for callbacks because the data-bindings will just be empty until the data arrives and then magically filled in. Now you have a reusable service to get data in all of your controllers.

Wow! everything is so simple and clean, and it just works! Angular is awesome! Then, of course, when you go to write an actual app that needs more than one controller, and the controllers all depend on the same data, and you add something called "business logic" that is also shared and uses this data, you immediately realize things aren't so simple.

First of all, as soon as you add business logic that has to use the data from the server (like with any real app), your clean code with no callbacks is broken. You now have to implement callbacks everywhere, because you have to wait for the data to arrive before you can use it. Second, prototypal scope inheritance becomes unreliable because you don't know if the data from other controllers has loaded yet or not. Worst of all though, there is nothing in these tutorials about how you are supposed to keep the data in sync between controllers, and with the server. If the data is modified in the scope of one controller, somehow all of the other controller scopes need to be updated as well...

These are just some of the complexities that are introduced even with a pretty simple app that doesn't even use routing. I'm trying to make a simple calculator that doesn't persist data, and I am stuck with all of these problems and questions and can't find any real solutions.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of a good tutorial, example, or book that will fill in these missing holes without getting into complex parts of angular that my app doesn't require?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the rant, this has been very frustrating :/

Comment: where are u feeling pain of using callbacks , angular is using promise so you can leverage use of promise instead of callbacks and prototype inheritance should not bother your sharing work

Comment: [OOP](http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2014/02/14/angularjs-services-inheritance/)

Comment: @AjayBeniwal The callbacks aren't my worst problem as I mentioned, it's just the tutorials are misleading and don't really go into the complexity introduced by callbacks and promises. Please don't try and single out a specific thing in my post, and look at the whole picture. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. A good source for learning AngularJS? A better alternative to using callbacks? A way to share data between controllers?
I have watched some of the [AngularJS videos on Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Find?highlight=true&searchTerm=AngularJS) I found them very helpful and informative. Some of the videos on there are top notch. The video player lets you watch videos at 2X the speed when you want to rush through it. You can get a free trial for 10 days though you would have to pay $29 a month after that.

Comment: Angular is good for single page apps. Controllers will house most of the business logic in `$scope` functions. Services house objects that come back from the server. If logic is tightly coupled with the data & is applicable across multiple controllers, I put it in the service as a function. Directives are global. That's about all the complexity I can think of.

Comment: @FooL Thanks, you've summed up exactly what's wrong with every tutorial that tries to explain angular so simply, when it really isn't.

Answer (score 4):

I am far from being an angularJS expert, I am actually in the process of learning too. However, we are almost done with our first angularJS MVP at work so maybe I can share some of my experience. Here are a few patterns I learnt

- Your controllers should be minimalist and call services and factories.
- Controller actions are triggered by `$emit` and `$broadcast` which is what keeps everything in sync. I have controllers with just a list of `$scope.$on('onCustomAction',function(event,params){ $scope.myObject.doSomething(); })`. Ideally, it should be a minimalist list of those.
- In ng-click, you should have methods like `myObject.fancyMethod()` where `myObject` is part of the '$scope`.
- Put small pieces of reusable html that have their own little controller in directives. I am quite late on that but I am starting to have a few.
- Use ng-include for large pieces of html that you need to move around (ie: modal windows, main content, sidebars etc).
- Remember, if it's not in the $scope, it might as well not exist.
- Services can call other services and can be used for singletons and instanced objects. They should be the meat of your code.

Hope this helps. Feel free to argue each of those items.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who was experiencing the same type of angularjs frustration. I get it.  What helped me immensely was Jeremy Howard's 4 part tutotial, ["Angularjs End to end web app in under an hour".](http://jphoward.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/end-to-end-web-app-in-under-an-hour/)  It uses ASP.net but I am sure most of the back end examples would be easily reproducible with any other framework.

Here is a quick and dirty laundry list of why I found this useful.

1. Example is a Todo CRUD app that could be used as a template for most other web apps.
2. The videos move at a reasonable pace and are broken down into logical functional areas.
3. Jeremy uses some of the techniques you described above that are in other videos such as promises, directives, factories, services, link functions, controllers, etc.  However, the examples he uses do have **substance** as they work within the context of the todo app.
4. Lastly, it becomes clear in watching Jeremy going through his tutorial that being **very** organized in how you structure your back end will make your front end angular app so much better and powerful.  Think separation of concerns to a whole other level.

I could go on and on but one thing I can say, is that Jeremy's tutorials not only made me better at angularjs but made me better at being a full stack developer.

Do yourself a favor and check it out.  You won't regret it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice tutorial on data model dealing with your problem:

*"Worst of all though, there is nothing in these tutorials about how you are supposed to keep the data in sync between controllers, and with the server. If the data is modified in the scope of one controller, somehow all of the other controller scopes need to be updated as well..."*

http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/